# export html to the word on the page number i want

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html2canvas

i solved that html export word using html2canvas (under code is correct, it can work well)

but i want to html export word  on the page number i want(for example, i want to export html to word second page)

my code here

```
 function ExportToDoc(filename = "") {
    var img = new Image();
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("pyramid")).then((canvas) => {
      img.src = canvas.toDataURL();

      var HtmlHead =
        "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></head><body>";
      var EndHtml = "</body></html>";
      var html =
        HtmlHead + "<img class='hide' src='" + img.src + "'/>" + EndHtml;

      var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", html], {
        type: "application/msword",
      });
      var url =
        "data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8," +
        encodeURIComponent(html);
      filename = filename ? filename + ".doc" : "Document.doc";
      var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
      document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
      if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
      } else {
        downloadLink.href = url;
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        downloadLink.click();
      }
      document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
    });
  }
```